# Why won't .filter() work in Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

This is the line:

```
songs = songs.filter(function (el) {
  return el.album==album;
});
```

This is the error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

This Works 100% fine in Chrome. What's going on?

Comment: I posted my answer before I saw Paul's.  Is songs an array or jQuery object?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`Array.filter()` isn't included in IE until version 9.

You could use this to implement it:

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter)
{
  Array.prototype.filter = function(fun /*, thisp */)
  {
    "use strict";

    if (this === void 0 || this === null)
      throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun !== "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var res = [];
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in t)
      {
        var val = t[i]; // in case fun mutates this
        if (fun.call(thisp, val, i, t))
          res.push(val);
      }
    }

    return res;
  };
}
```

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Or since you are using jQuery, you can wrap your array into a jQuery object first:

```
songs = $(songs).filter(function(){
  return this.album==album;
});
```

Comment: The argument for the filter function is an index.  To get the actual element, you can simply use `this`. http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: You could also do i,v in the function, where v is the array and i is the element.

Comment: this works well. I just had to remove the if condition `if (!Array.prototype.filter)` to make it work for me in IE

Answer (score 1):

Use es5-shim, so you can use filter/indexOf in IE8!

Facebook's react.js using that too.

```
  <!--[if lte IE 8]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/react/js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/react/js/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/react/js/es5-sham.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
```

https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim

Answer (score 0):

Does using the attr() function work?

```
songs = songs.filter(function (index) {
    return $(this).attr("album") == album;
});
```