# JQuery .filter() in IE8

Tags: jquery, arrays, internet-explorer-8, filter

It looks like IE8 doesn't support the Jquery `.filter()` method - [Why won't .filter() work in Internet Explorer 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153470/why-wont-filter-work-in-interent-explorer-8)

I have the following code which filters a dropdown list

```
if($('#deliveryPostcodeEstimator').length > 0) {
        $('.shippingregionselector').hide();
        $('#deliveryPostcodeEstimator')
            .blur(function() {
                //Set to default
                $('select[name=country] option:last').prop('selected', true);
                //var defaultPostcode = 'GL50';
                //$("select[name=country] option").filter(function() {
                //  return $(this).text() == defaultPostcode; 
                //}).prop('selected', true);
                //Set to matching postcode value if set
                $('select[name=country] option').filter(function(index) { 
                    return ($(this).text() == $('#deliveryPostcodeEstimator').val().toUpperCase().substring(0,4).trim()) 
                }).prop('selected', true);
                //Submit
                var thisForm = $(this).closest("form");
                thisForm.submit();
            })
            .keyup(function() {
                $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
            });
        $('button.pcodechange').click(function() {
            var thisForm = $(this).closest("form");
            thisForm.submit();
        });
    }
```

The problem line is

```
return ($(this).text() == $('#deliveryPostcodeEstimator').val().toUpperCase().substring(0,4).trim())
```

Which gives the following error

`Object doesn't support this property or method`
How do I 'wrap this in an object' as suggested in the previous post?

Thanks

Comment: jQuery.filter and array.filter are different things

Comment: `It looks like IE8 doesn't support the Jquery .filter() method` Do you get an error or any warning message in the console in the browser debugging tools? Have you run it in Chromer/FireFox as well? Have you tried making a [**fiddle**](http://jsFiddle.net) to check if it all works there?

Comment: OK. So perhaps my question should be more along the lines of 'How can I get this to work in IE8?' It's fine in Chrome/FF

Comment: The error is “Object doesn't support this property or method”

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @Jeepstone: Does the message say which method? Theoretically it could be any of the ones in the line `.text()`, `.val()`, `.toUpperCase()`, `.substring()` or `.trim()` Can you make each action a separate line assigning the result to a variable? that way it would propably be easier to figure out which command is causing the problem.

Comment: Hi, I'm using 1.8.3.  François, the trim() could be a good shout. I'll split the lines out and see where it breaks.

Comment: Looks like it's the trim().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error is probably because of your `.trim()` call.

`String.prototype.trim` is not available for Internet Explorer 8 according to this table:
http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

You could use jQuery.trim instead:

```
 var search = $.trim($('#deliveryPostcodeEstimator').val().toUpperCase().substring(0,4));
 $('select[name=country] option').filter(function(index) { 
   return $(this).text() == search; 
 }).prop('selected', true);
```

You could also use a pure javascript solution which is described in cernunnos link:

[.trim() in JavaScript not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie)

Comment: +1 Nice find. Also states that in the MDN Documentation under [**trim() - Browser Compatibility**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: This appears to be the correct answer, and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie might be useful to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

IE9 and onwards support .filter()

Here is what you can do:
Define your own Filter.

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter) {
  Array.prototype.filter = function (fun /*, thisp */) {
    "use strict";

    if (this === void 0 || this === null)
        throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun !== "function")
        throw new TypeError();

    var res = [];
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (i in t) {
            var val = t[i]; // in case fun mutates this
            if (fun.call(thisp, val, i, t))
                res.push(val);
        }
    }

    return res;
};
}
```