# How to find item from an object with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have my data object:

```
var elements = {
        'element' : {
            'name' : 'test',
                    'price' : '55'
        },
        'element' : {
            'name' : 'letev',
                    'price': '223'
        }
    };
```

Now, I don't know how can I find each **element** by name for example.
I need to find element by name test, and then acces it's other parameters (price,..)

Comment: This object is impossible. Key names must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your object was an array instead of the syntax you used:

```
var elements = [
    {
        'name' : 'test',
        'price' : '55'
    },{
        'name' : 'letev',
        'price': '223'
    }
];
```

You can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the element out like this:

```
searchName = 'test';
elements.filter(function(element){
    return element.name == searchName;
});
```

This will only return the elements that have `'test'` as name.

Or as a function:

```
function filterByName(array, namr){
    array.filter(function(element){
        return element.name == name;
    });
}
```

Called like this:

```
array result = filterByName(elements, 'test');
```

In case you need to support IE 8 or lower, you can use a [polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153470/why-wont-filter-work-in-interent-explorer-8) for `Array.prototype.filter`.

Answer (score 1):

You must change elements to array:

```
var elements = [
    {
        'name' : 'test',
        'price' : '55'
    },
    {
        'name' : 'letev',
        'price': '223'
    }
];

function findElementByName(name, elementsForSearch) {
    if (name) {
        elementsForSearch.filter(function(elem){
            return elem.name === 'name';
        });
        return elementsForSearch[0];
    }
    return {};
}

alert(findElementByName('test', elements).name)
```

Comment: use `Array.filter`. it's much easier to maintain.

Comment: Yes, thanks, it's ES 5.1,but checked it support (IE9+ and modern). I think I can use it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
var elements = [
  {
    'name' : 'test',
    'price' : '55'
  },
  {
    'name' : 'letev',
    'price': '223'
  }
];

var search = 'letev';
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if (elements[i].name == search) {
    alert('found!');
    break;
  }
}
```

Or using `Array.filter`:

```
var search = 'letev';
var output = elements.filter(function(element) {
  return element.name == search;
});
```

Comment: use `Array.filter` instead of manually iterating the results.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that if your `elements` object was an array, i.e.

```
var elements = [{
        'element' : {
            'name' : 'test',
                    'price' : '55'
        },
        'element' : {
            'name' : 'letev',
                    'price': '223'
        }
    }];

var price;
for (var i=0; i  <elements.length; i++) { 
    if (elements[i].name === 'test') {
        price = elements[i].price;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var List= (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring);
    var result= List["element"].Children().Select(node => node["name"]== "Test").ToList();
```