# search dropdown values on based of textbox type in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dropdown with more than 100 values, and I have a textbox. When i type anything in the textbox, then the dropdown filter automatically. I wrote this code:

```
$('#txtSearchText').on('input', function () {
    var val = this.value.toLowerCase();       
    $('#ddlData> option').hide()
    .filter(function () {
        return this.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) > -1;
    }).show();

});`
```

It's working fine in Chrome & firefox browser , but it's not working for IE browser, so please suggest me what i need to do for IE browser...`

Comment: Array.filter() isn't included in IE until version 9. Which version are you using? Take a look as this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7153509/1179430

Comment: it's not working in any version of IE , i am using IE11..and can you please write code acc. to my condition

Comment: please add HTML as well. and formatting would be nice

Comment: i have removed hide,but it's not working in IE... i already told you,it's working fine in chrome & Mozilla, but not working in IE. so tell me solution for IE only,can you please write code..

Comment: Vipin, try to be a little more polite, we're not here to write your code.

Comment: I can understand friend, i already written code, i just asking what modification i need to resolve my problem , i am going to stuck too much ,

Answer (score 0):

The problem is quite simple.

Hiding `<option>` tag is not supported cross browser. Similarly events on same tag are not supported.

Choices are remove or disable ... or use one of the many `<select>` replacement plugins

Comment: as i said.... remove or disable. If you remove;  store a cached copy so you can filter that to rebuild the select

Comment: Or use a select replacement plugin

Comment: $('#txtSearchText').on('input', function () {
        var val = this.value.toLowerCase();
       
        $('#txtResultData > option').remove()
        .filter(function () {
            return this.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) > -1;
        }).show();
    });   is it right acc. to you ?

Comment: no...you removed them all. Also can't do show...because they can't be hidden in the first place

Comment: woah there cowboy....this isn't a code writing service and the idea that anyone should reply to you `asap` is not polite. Everyone here does this on their own time. There are 100's of similar posts here and all  over the web. Do some research

Comment: I know man, i am searching and found so many codes but not getting any genuine code, i am going to stuck for this problem , i thought you have idea to fix this, that 's why i was expecting a genuine result from you , but i think u also don't have idea to fix this problem , so if you know about this problem , please tell me , because i am stuck too much  to solve this issue.

Comment: This is not my condition friend,my condition is one textbox and one dropdown, i will filter dropdown option value on the basis of textbox type value..

Comment: The filtering is the same thing. Just a minor change to adapt the code. They are both event based

Comment: i know friend, i have changed and tried it,but still i am stuck, so please if have solution than please tell me

Comment: I gave you an extremely similar example. If you can't modify it...hire another developer that can. This isn't a code writing service

Comment: hey man, i also have written so many codes, ok , when you are not able to create this functionality , don't say that you are a developer , because a good developer never give comment, he gives support and output, if you really a good developer, than why you are afraiding from this simple functioanlity....

Comment: I know very well that this is not a code writing service, but you don't know that stackoveryflow provide a service,where you can talk with developer and can get help ....code i already provided you, i just asking a simple modification in my code, you are giving suggestion and passing comment, but u don't have solution and don't have time to modify my simple code.